# PHP сравнение чисел с произвольной точностью

Tags: php

Могут ли возникнут проблемы с неточностью при сравнении таких чисел: `decimal(11,8)`, 
Пример: `10.00002111 > 10.00002112`

P.S. 
Я стараюсь в таких ситуациях всегда использовать BCMATH, но не до конца понимаю когда этим можно пренебречь, (при какой точности могут быть ошибки)
PHP 7.2

Comment: Используйте [bccomp()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.bccomp.php)

Comment: Я стараюсь в таких ситуациях всегда использовать BCMATH, но не до конца понимаю когда этим можно пренебречь, (при какой точности могут быть ошибки)